# My app keeps crashing after splash activity finishes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

my app when I run it only shows the splash screen then crashes.
at first it was giving me "app keep on stopping" when I run it but now it runs the splash screen then crashes.

Splash screen.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private boolean mIsBackButtonPressed;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(Constants.pref_name,MODE_PRIVATE);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if (!mIsBackButtonPressed) {
                    if(getIntent().hasExtra("action_type")){
                        Intent intent= new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        String action_type=getIntent().getExtras().getString("action_type");
                        String receiverid=getIntent().getExtras().getString("senderid");
                        String title=getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
                        String icon=getIntent().getExtras().getString("icon");

                        intent.putExtra("icon",icon);
                        intent.putExtra("action_type",action_type);
                        intent.putExtra("receiverid",receiverid);
                        intent.putExtra("title",title);


                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    else
                        GPSStatus();
                }
            }
        }, 2000);



    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        // set the flag to true so the next activity won't start up
        mIsBackButtonPressed = true;
        super.onBackPressed();

    }



    public void GPSStatus(){
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean GpsStatus = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(!GpsStatus)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "On Location in High Accuracy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS),2);

        }else {


            GetCurrentlocation();
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==2){
            GPSStatus();
        }
    }


    private void GetCurrentlocation() {
        FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            enable_location();
            return;
        }

        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                        if (location != null) {

                            // if we successfully get the location of the user then we will save the locatio into
                            //locally and go to the Main view
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                            editor.putString(Constants.Lat,""+location.getLatitude());
                            editor.putString(Constants.Lon,""+location.getLongitude());
                            editor.commit();
                            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_from_right, R.anim.out_to_left);
                            finish();
                        }
                        else  {

                            if(sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.Lat,"").equals("") || sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.Lon,"").equals("") ){
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putString(Constants.Lat,"33.738045");
                                editor.putString(Constants.Lon,"73.084488");
                                editor.commit();
                            }
                            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_from_right, R.anim.out_to_left);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }



    private void enable_location() {
        EnableLlocationFragment enable_llocationFragment = new EnableLlocationFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in_from_right, R.anim.out_to_left,R.anim.in_from_left,R.anim.out_to_right);
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        transaction.replace(R.id.splash, enable_llocationFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }

}
```

I believe it must be something with my MainActivity that is causing the problem,
this is the main activity code
main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    long mBackPressed;


    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static String user_id;
    public static String user_name;
    public static String image;
    public static String image1;
    public static String birthday;
    public static String about;
    public static String purchased;
    public static String token;
    BaseApp baseApp;
    LinearLayout llsearch;
    DatabaseReference rootref;
    AboutModels modelAbout;
    public static String title="none";

    EditText search;

    public  static MainActivity mainActivity;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    BottomNavigationView navigation;
    int previousSelect = 0;
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home:
                    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    navigationItemSelected(0);
                    loadFrag(homeFragment, getString(R.string.menu_home), fragmentManager);
                    llsearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;
                case R.id.property:
                    PropertyFragment propertyFragment = new PropertyFragment();
                    navigationItemSelected(1);
                    loadFrag(propertyFragment, getString(R.string.menu_property), fragmentManager);
                    llsearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return true;
                case R.id.favourite:
                    FavouriteFragment matchFragment = new FavouriteFragment();
                    navigationItemSelected(2);
                    loadFrag(matchFragment, getString(R.string.menu_favourite), fragmentManager);
                    llsearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return true;
                case R.id.chat:
                    MessageFragment messageFragment = new MessageFragment();
                    navigationItemSelected(3);
                    loadFrag(messageFragment, getString(R.string.menu_chat), fragmentManager);
                    llsearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return true;
                case R.id.user:
                    ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    navigationItemSelected(4);
                    loadFrag(profileFragment, getString(R.string.menu_profile), fragmentManager);
                    llsearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    private BaseApp FirebaseInstanceId;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout mAdViewLayout = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        BannerAds.ShowBannerAds(getApplicationContext(), mAdViewLayout);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        llsearch = findViewById(R.id.llsearch);
        baseApp = BaseApp.getInstance();
        navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        modelAbout = new AboutModels();
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        loadFrag(homeFragment, getString(R.string.menu_home), fragmentManager);
        mainActivity =this;
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.pref_name, MODE_PRIVATE);
        user_id = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.uid, "null");
        user_name = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.f_name, "") + " " + sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.l_name, "");
        image =sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.u_pic,"null");
        image1 =sharedPreferences.getString("image1","null");
        token=sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.device_token, FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
        rootref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        search = findViewById(R.id.search);

        search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                String sSearch= search.getText().toString().trim();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(sSearch)) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Column Can't be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("searchtext", sSearch);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

        });

        PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
        try {
            packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Constants.versionname=packageInfo.versionName;



    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (baseApp.getIsLogin()) {
            rootref.child("Users").child(user_id).child("token").setValue(token);
        } else {
            rootref.child("Users").child(user_id).child("token").setValue("null");
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Check_version();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        int count = this.getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (count == 0) {
            if (mBackPressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            } else {
                clickDone();

            }
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void clickDone() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setPositiveButton("YES!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }



    public void Check_version(){
        VersionChecker versionChecker = new VersionChecker(this);
        versionChecker.execute();
    }

    public void loadFrag(Fragment f1, String name, FragmentManager fm) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.Container, f1, name);
        ft.commit();
    }

    public void navigationItemSelected(int position) {
        previousSelect = position;
    }




}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.otacodes.goestate">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <application
        android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Constants.BaseApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-1300058369369222~7049892454"/>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.otacodes.goestate.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.LoginFormActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/Login_phone_A"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.RegisterActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.AllPropByCatActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.AllPropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.AllPopularActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.AllPropByCityActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.SearchActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.MyPropertyActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.PropertyDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.FilterSearchActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.PicklocationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/noActionBar"
             />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/coloraccent" />

        <service android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Utils.NotificationReceive"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <activity android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.AboutActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.PrivacyActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.BlockActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.FullImageActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.otacodes.goestate.Activity.AddPropertyActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat

```
2022-01-05 01:50:49.624 4111-8222/? I/ExperimentPackageManage: Package com.google.android.os.statsd name not found! Using module version.
2022-01-05 01:50:49.626 4111-8222/? I/ExperimentPackageManage: Package com.google.android.os.statsd name not found! Using module version.
2022-01-05 01:50:49.631 4111-8222/? I/ayxc: updateFromConfigurations DeviceConfig for namespace virtualization_framework_native [CONTEXT service_id=204 ]
2022-01-05 01:50:49.572 3623-3623/? V/SettingsProvider: Notifying for 0: content://settings/config/app_standby/Phenotype_flags
2022-01-05 01:50:49.635 3623-3623/? V/SettingsProvider: Notifying for 0: content://settings/config/virtualization_framework_native/Phenotype_flags

2022-01-05 01:50:51.048 6662-6662/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: onUnbind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.feedback.internal.IFeedbackService cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsBoundBrokerService }

2022-01-05 01:50:52.610 1768-5915/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2022-01-05 01:50:52.787 6662-6662/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: onUnbind: Intent { act=com.google.android.mdd.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsBoundBrokerService }
2022-01-05 01:50:53.138 4111-6600/? W/Nearby: Failed attempt #3 out of 3 for RestoreDeviceName [CONTEXT service_id=49 ]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: BluetoothAdapter not ready yet!
        at aswl.d(:com.google.android.gms@214815031@21.48.15 (100700-414534850):2)
        at aswj.run(:com.google.android.gms@214815031@21.48.15 (100700-414534850):0)
        at cmvg.call(:com.google.android.gms@214815031@21.48.15 (100700-414534850):0)
        at cmvl.a(:com.google.android.gms@214815031@21.48.15 (100700-414534850):2)
        at cmvl.b(:com.google.android.gms@214815031@21.48.15 (100700-414534850):0)
        at aswk.run(:com.google.android.gms@214815031@21.48.15 (100700-414534850):5)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at xtk.run(:com.google.android.gms@214815031@21.48.15 (100700-414534850):5)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at xzm.run(:com.google.android.gms@214815031@21.48.15 (100700-414534850):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

2022-01-05 01:50:55.826 3623-3647/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2022-01-05 01:50:55.826 6662-6662/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: onUnbind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.download.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsBoundBrokerService }
2022-01-05 01:50:55.826 3623-3647/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
2022-01-05 01:50:55.869 6662-6662/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: onUnbind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.ocr.service.internal.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsInternalApiService }
2022-01-05 01:50:55.974 7623-7658/? I/Dialer: OmtpVvmCarrierCfgHlpr - OmtpEvent:CONFIG_STATUS_SMS_TIME_OUT
2022-01-05 01:50:55.976 7623-7623/? I/Dialer: RetryPolicy - discarding deferred status: configuration_state=4
2022-01-05 01:50:55.979 7623-7623/? I/Dialer: VvmTaskExecutor - no more tasks, stopping service if no task are added in 5000 millis
2022-01-05 01:50:55.980 7623-7623/? I/Dialer: VvmTaskReceiver - task received
2022-01-05 01:50:55.980 7623-7623/? I/Dialer: VvmTaskReceiver - TaskExecutor already running
2022-01-05 01:50:55.980 7623-7623/? I/Dialer: Task.createTask - create task:com.android.voicemail.impl.ActivationTask
2022-01-05 01:50:55.980 7623-7623/? I/Dialer: RetryPolicy - retry #1 for com.android.voicemail.impl.ActivationTask@d3f6d93 queued, executing in 5000
2022-01-05 01:50:55.981 7623-7623/? I/Dialer: VvmTaskExecutor - com.android.voicemail.impl.ActivationTask@d3f6d93 added
2022-01-05 01:50:55.981 7623-7623/? I/Dialer: VvmTaskExecutor - minimal wait time:5000
2022-01-05 01:50:55.981 7623-7623/? I/Dialer: VvmTaskExecutor - sleep for 5000 millis
2022-01-05 01:50:58.350 4111-8109/? E/GCM: Missing checkin config file
2022-01-05 01:50:58.350 4111-8109/? W/GCM: GCM FAILED TO INITIALIZE - missing checkin
2022-01-05 01:50:58.609 1768-5915/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: 
L_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2022-01-05 01:51:00.984 7623-7658/? I/Dialer: VvmTaskExecutor - executing task com.android.voicemail.impl.ActivationTask@d3f6d93
2022-01-05 01:51:00.984 7623-7658/? I/Dialer: PreOMigrationHandler - ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, ***, UserHandle{0} already migrated
2022-01-05 01:51:01.021 7671-7685/? I/VoicemailNotifier: receivers for android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED :[]
2022-01-05 01:51:01.024 7623-7658/? I/Dialer: VvmActivationTask - VVM content provider configured - vvm_type_cvvm
2022-01-05 01:51:01.025 7623-7658/? I/Dialer: OmtpVvmCarrierCfgHlpr - OmtpEvent:CONFIG_ACTIVATING
2022-01-05 01:51:01.040 7671-7687/? I/VoicemailNotifier: receivers for android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED :[]
2022-01-05 01:51:01.047 3894-4110/? I/LocationAccessPolicy: Allowing com.android.dialer fine because it doesn't target API 29 yet. Please fix this app. Called from getServiceStateForSubscriber
2022-01-05 01:51:01.050 3894-4110/? I/LocationAccessPolicy: Allowing com.android.dialer coarse because it doesn't target API 29 yet. Please fix this app. Called from getServiceStateForSubscriber
```

Comment: "my app keeps crashing" I hope you understand that this is pretty vague. do you have an error message/error log/stacktrace?

Comment: nothing is showing in my logcat @Stultuske

Comment: added the error log

Answer (score -1):

Sorry because I can't comment, you should rebuild app, then open logcat and select error flag to view error log (default is verbose)
With only codes above, we can't help anything

Comment: posting comments as answers might make it even take more time before you can comment